# Can style "display: block" overrule "display: none" of media print CSS?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Here is an HTML element:

```
<div id="cboxOverlay" style="display: block; opacity: 0.9; cursor: pointer;" class="price_match_no_print"></div>
```

Here is some CSS:

```
@media print {
    .price_match_no_print {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Now when I print the page, the above HTML element comes on the print?

Does the style `display: block` overrules the `display: none` of `@media print`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`@media`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule) rules themselves don't have any specificity and because you're adding CSS rules via inline styles, they will always override any external styles that aren't using an [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) rule. So in this case, your only option is:

```
@media print {
    .price_match_no_print {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you got your answer in whilst I was typing mine! Just to clarify for the question owner: this is the correct answer.  The suggestion by Ernie that it isn't possible is mistaken.  !important will overwrite any other styles attached to an element, whether from the stylesheet, or applied inline.